# Hosting Nuget packages on a network folder/share

Tags: nuget

I have a network share that I dropped a nuget package I created into.  I configured Nuget in VS2010 to add the share as a package source.  However when I select it, it shows no packages.

If I have the package in a local folder, it works fine.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on both the share and in the file system? I have a UNC share running successfully as a package source, so it should work.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but as opposed to simply dropping in the packages manually (as it sounds like you're doing), you should try using the NuGet CLI's [`add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#add) command to properly set up the network share feed's folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to test. Open Windows Explorer using the same credential you use with VS2010 and point to the nuget share. If you can see packages there, then you should see them in VS2010 also. If you can't see the files in Windows Explorer - then check the permissions as @PHeiberg suggests and make sure you have list and read. Since groups are probably in use, search for your login from effective permissions as in this screenshot:
[image]